# Read text from file line by line to 2 strings variables

Tags: java, file, stream

I have a file with some words saved in a text file like that:

```
Koraa
Orakaa
Balaes
Ealaaab
Araqko
```

I need to know how to read it using Java like below:

```
string firstWord = "Koraa";
```

and the 2nd line in another string

```
string secondWord = "Orakaa";
```

then I will do some stuff on those 2 strings then secondWord & firstWord contents' will be replaced with next 2 lines in the same file !
for example:

```
firstWord = "Balaes";
secondWord = "Ealaaab";
```

... etc the operation will be looping on all these words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an `ArrayList` of `String` and read separate lines from a file using `Scanner`.

```
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    File file = new File("example.txt");

    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        while (scanner.hasNext())
            al.add(scanner.nextLine())
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        scanner.close();
    }
```

You can refer to the individual words, in order, with `al.get(int index)`.

Comment: then al[0] will be firstWord for me and al[1] will be the 2nd word right !?

Comment: You refer to elements of the ArrayList with the `get(int index)` method, **NOT** with brackets `al[0]`. So yes, in this case `al.get(0)` would be firstWord, `al.get(1)` would be secondWord, etc.